# How to get the dropbox-php library with pear HTTP_OAUTH to work?

Tags: php, oauth, pear, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I've been struggelig to get the dropbox-php library to work, but the page where I try to use the classes outputs an error:

```
Warning: include(HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/OAuth/PEAR.php on line 47   

Warning: include(HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such  file or directory in /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/OAuth/PEAR.php on line 47

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/OAuth/PEAR.php on line 47

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox_Exception' with message 'The HTTP_OAuth_Consumer class could not be found! Did you install the pear HTTP_OAUTH class?' in /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/OAuth/PEAR.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/getmetadata.php(11): Dropbox_OAuth_PEAR->__construct('', '') #1 {main} thrown in /home/sensured/public_html/sensured.net/Dropbox/OAuth/PEAR.php on line 51
```

The pear HTTP_OAUTH class is installed (v 0.2.3), but its done though cpanel so I'm unsure where and don't even know if that has anything to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that PEAR's PHP directory is in your `include_path`.

Find the path with

```
$ pear config-get php_dir
```

then add it to your `php.ini`'s `include_path` directive. Restart your web server software afterwards to activate the new settings .